# Different result of PCA using python's sklearn and matlab's pca

Tags: python, matlab, pca

I generate the same matrix in matlab and python:

```
 1     2     3     4     5
 6     7     8     9    10
11    12    13    14    15
16    17    18    19    20
21    22    23    24    25
```

Then I apply pca Respectively to get the principal components coefficients.

Matlab code:

```
X = reshape([1:25], 5, 5);
X = X'
[cofe, S, latent] = pca(X)
```

result:

```
cofe =

0.4472    0.8944         0         0
0.4472   -0.2236    0.8660   -0.0000
0.4472   -0.2236   -0.2887    0.8165
0.4472   -0.2236   -0.2887   -0.4082
0.4472   -0.2236   -0.2887   -0.4082
```

Python code:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import numpy as np
pca = PCA()
A = np.array(range(1, 26), dtype=float).reshape([5, 5])
print(A)
pca.fit(A)
print(np.transpose(pca.components_))
```

result:

```
[[-0.4472136   0.          0.          0.          0.89442719]
 [-0.4472136  -0.5        -0.5        -0.5        -0.2236068 ]
 [-0.4472136   0.83333333 -0.16666667 -0.16666667 -0.2236068 ]
 [-0.4472136  -0.16666667  0.83333333 -0.16666667 -0.2236068 ]
 [-0.4472136  -0.16666667 -0.16666667  0.83333333 -0.2236068 ]]
```

Two column of the results are the same, but others are quite different. Then I tried to normalized the result of python code, cause I saw that the result of matlab is normalized, but the result remained.

Could someone tell me why are they different?

Answer (score 4):

Its irrelevant if they are the same or not, they are "zero". Their eigenvalue is zero. Because of your matrix, you can describe the entire data with a single principal component with 100% of accuracy, therefore the following principal components are just noise.

One can see that by looking at the matrix (all its rows are linearly dependent, none of them are independent), but easier to use MATLAB's inbuilt functionality.

```
[cofe, S, latent,~,explained,~] = pca(X)

explained =

  100.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
    0.0000
```

The first PCA is 100% of the data, the following ones are 0% of the data. If they are 0% of the data, their values are irrelevant.